# How to append to lines in a file that do not contain a specific pattern using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a flat file as follows:

```
11|aaa
11|bbb|NO|xxx
11|ccc
11|ddd|NO|yyy
```

For lines that do not contain **|NO|**, I would like to add the string **|YES|** at the end. So my file should look like:

```
11|aaa|YES|
11|bbb|NO|xxx
11|ccc|YES|
11|ddd|NO|yyy
```

I am using AIX and **sed -i** option for inline replacements is not available. Hence, currently I'm using the following code to do this:

```
#Get the lines that do not contain |NO|
LINES=`grep -v "|NO|" file`

for i in LINES
do
    sed "/$i/{s/$/|YES|/;}" file > temp
    mv temp file
done
```

The above works, however, as my file contains over 40000 lines, it takes about 3 hours to run. I believe it is taking so much time because it has to search for each line and write to a temp file. Is there a faster way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If temp.txt is your file, try:

```
awk '$0 !~ /NO/ {print $0 "|YES|"} $0 ~ /NO/ {print}' temp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well :) 
If I didn't want to append YES to lines containing either NO or aaa, how can I modify the above command ?

Comment: You should use the '|' (alternative) regexp character, like this

awk '$0 !~ /NO|aaa/ {print $0 "|YES|"} $0 ~ /NO|aaa/ {print}' temp.txt

As a matter of interest, what was the speed difference with your test case?

Comment: Super. This is just what I want. The operation now takes under a minute to execute. My previous logic used to take about 3 hours :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

This will be quick:

```
sed '/NO/!s/$/|YES|/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple with `awk`. Put the code below into a script and run it with `awk -f script file > temp`

```
/\|NO\|/ { print; next; } # just print anything which contains |NO| and read next line
{ print $0 "|YES|"; } # For any other line (no pattern), print the line + |YES|
```

I'm not sure about `awk` regexps; if it doesn't work, try to remove the two `\` in the first pattern.